# Improper Integral of a general function in $x>0$

Tags: integration, physics

I'm a first year Physics student and currently practicing questions from our 'Introductory Mathematics for Physicists' course.
I ran into a problem dealing with a proof of improper integral of a general function.
We were needed to prove that in $x>0$:$\\$
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx= \frac12 \int_0^\infty \biggl[f(x)+\frac{1}{x^2}f(\frac1x)\biggl]dx$$

$$-$$The solution that was given to us was this:

$$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx=\biggl|\frac1u=x, -\frac{du}{u^2}=dx\biggl|=$$
$$\int_\infty^0 f(\frac1u)(-\frac{du}{u^2})=-\int_\infty^0 \frac{1}{u^2}f(\frac1u)du=$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{u^2}f(\frac1u)du=$$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}f(\frac1x)dx$$

I don't understand that last transition. When I solved it by myself I got:

$$\int_0^\infty x^2f(x)dx$$

What am I missing here?

Comment: What do you call the *last* transition ?

Comment: the variable $u$ is just renamed $x$, no further substitution is done.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Formatting tip: you can get adjustable-size parentheses using `\left` and `\right`.  `$f\left(\frac1x\right)$` is displayed as $f\left(\frac1x\right)$

Comment: The variable of integration doesn't matter.  Call it whatever you like.  (Or if you like, make the substitution $u=x,\ du=dx$.)

Comment: I've set it in a separate line for it to be clear. peter-melech do you mean the change itself is only with the name of the variable? I thought that I was supposed to substitute it back to x, i see now, thank you. @saulspatz thank you for the tip, with the previous explanation and yours I understand now, thanks for the help.